# SQL: Finding customers with no spend in a category

Tags: sql, business-intelligence, netezza

I think I've been working on this too long because I'm having a hard time answering a pretty simple question: In a retail environment, which customers have not spent money in categories for which I'm offering a coupon?

Consider the following data:

```
-- The offer ID and the category for which it is valid.
select * from t_offers
OFFER   CAT_NBR
foo34   34
xxx30   30
baz60   60
bar50   50

-- The customer ID (HH) and their total spending by all
-- categories (not just the ones for which coupons are being offered).
-- PLEASE NOTE that when a customer has zero spend, there will NOT be an
--             entry in this table for that category.
select * from t_catspend
HH  CAT_NBR SPEND
1   30      5
1   60      7
2   34      8
```

What I'm trying to get is this:  For each offer in `t_offers`, the `HH` ID for each customer that does not have spending in that offer's category.  For example, for offer foo34 I should get HH #1, since HH #1 does not show any spend for that category (no entry for cat 34 for HH #1).

So one's first instinct when looking for null data is an outer join.  So I tried a left join on `cat_nbr`.  But that only gets me the customers that do have spending; I can't figure out how to tell me the ID of customers with *no* spending in that category.

This is on Netezza, if it matters.

Thanks very much in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.HH
FROM    t_catspend a
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  null
            FROM    t_offers b
                    INNER JOIN t_catspend c
                        ON c.CAT_NBR = b.CAT_NBR
            WHERE   b.offer = 'foo34' AND
                    a.HH = c.HH
        )
GROUP   BY a.HH
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11dfb/19)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*an offer that spends on all HH returns empty*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7fdc8/1)

OUTPUT

```
╔════╗
║ HH ║
╠════╣
║  1 ║
╚════╝
```

**UPDATE**

```
SELECT  b.*, a.*
FROM    t_offers a
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT HH FROM t_catspend GROUP BY HH) b
        LEFT JOIN t_catspend x
          ON    a.CAT_NBR = x.CAT_NBR AND
                b.HH = x.HH
WHERE   x.CAT_NBR IS NULL
        -- AND a.offer = 'foo34'  -- <<== specific OFFER
ORDER   BY b.HH
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11dfb/30)

OUTPUT

```
╔════╦═══════╦═════════╗
║ HH ║ OFFER ║ CAT_NBR ║
╠════╬═══════╬═════════╣
║  1 ║ bar50 ║      50 ║
║  1 ║ foo34 ║      34 ║
║  2 ║ baz60 ║      60 ║
║  2 ║ bar50 ║      50 ║
║  2 ║ xxx30 ║      30 ║
╚════╩═══════╩═════════╝
```

Since you have mentioned that you have a very huge table, adding of compound `INDEX` will result in a faster query execution.

```
ALTER TABLE t_catspend ADD INDEX (HH, CAT_NBR)
```

and if possible `t_catspend.CAT_NBR` must reference `t_offers.CAT_NBR`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This looks good!  Is there a way to make it generic for all offers, instead of customised for foo34? Ideally I'd get back the offer code and hh ID for each qualifying thing ("qualifying" that there's no spend in the category, that is).

Comment: I have updated the answer to get the status of all users. You need to use `CROSS JOIN` on this to pair all offer to all `hh` values. Anyway, just don't hesitate to ask. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this?

```
SELECT b.cat_nbr, b.hh 
  FROM
(
 SELECT cat_nbr, hh
   FROM t_offers CROSS JOIN 
 ( 
   SELECT DISTINCT hh FROM t_catspend
 ) a
) b LEFT JOIN t_catspend s
    ON b.cat_nbr = s.cat_nbr AND b.hh = s.hh
 WHERE s.spend IS NULL
 GROUP BY b.cat_nbr, b.hh
```

Output based on provided sample data:

```
| CAT_NBR | HH |
----------------
|      30 |  2 |
|      34 |  1 |
|      50 |  1 |
|      50 |  2 |
|      60 |  2 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a85e4/1)**

Comment: how will you filter for record `foo34`?

Comment: @SkyDrive OP's exact words ***For each offer** in t_offers, the HH ID **for each customer** that does not have spending in that offer's category.* And it can be easily filtered by adding after `...) a WHERE cat_nbr = 34 ...`

Comment: Thanks, peterm.  I was going down the Cartesian join path when I decided to hop over to stackoverflow... It's unfortunate because there are about 30MM customers and a hundred or so categories.  Not the end of the world, but big!  I'll let you know how this works out.

Comment: @Chris IMHO, in your case you'll have to use `CROSS JOIN` one way or another. And JW's updated answer supports it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were on the right track, maybe missing WHERE criteria?

```
SELECT *
FROM t_catspend spend
LEFT JOIN t_offers offers
 ON spend.CAT_NBR = offers.CAT_NBR
WHERE offers.CAT_NBR IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know whether this is efficient or not but works.

```
SELECT DISTINCT HH, offer FROM t_offers, t_catspend
WHERE (HH, offer) NOT IN
(SELECT HH, offer FROM t_offers t1, t_catspend t2
WHERE t1.cat_nbr = t2.cat_nbr)
```